# Использовать данные из асинхронного метода

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Ребят имею асинхронный запрос на сервер:

```
public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

Как потом работать с данными полученными оттуда? Когда я пытаюсь обратиться к этим данным, они еще не получены.

Comment: И где пример использования?

Comment: в doInBackground я делаю запрос на сервер, в onPostExecute записываю в файл. Как мне дождаться записи в файл и потом работать с ним? При первом запуске говорит, что файл пуст, при втором запуске уже данные есть

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоило уточнить, что пишете - под Android.

Насчет проблемы - [учите мат. часть](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php)

`AsyncTask` имеет обязательный метод для переопределения, который зовётся `doInBackground` - в этом методе вы асинхронно получаете данные, нельзя создать `AsyncTask` не переопределив этот метод - будет синтаксическая ошибка.

Ваши действия по решению:

1)Читаете мат.часть

2)Переопределяете необходимые методы

3)profit

Comment: я понимаю,в doInBackground я делаю запрос на сервер, в onPostExecute записываю в файл. Как мне дождаться записи в файл и потом работать с ним? При первом запуске говорит, что файл пуст, при втором запуске уже данные есть